# Maths expression in the coordinates of rput

Tags: macros, pstricks, pst-node

I use `\rput[B](1.5,4.1){\( 1 \)}` to write a number at a specific place, now I would like to express an expression at the place of coordinates, for instance `\rput[B](2+#1,4.1){\( 1 \)}` where `#1` is an input of my macro, it returns an error `ERROR: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: A MWE would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For allow arithmetic in coordinates, you can use [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (or RPN for short). Here's a quick view on what you *might* be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/
\newcommand{\myput}[2][0]{%
  \rput[B](!1.5 #1 add 4.1){#2}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \SpecialCoor
  \rput[B](1.5,4.1){$1$}
  \myput[1]{$2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The RPN notation (used under PostScript) is described in section **54 Special coordinates** of the [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf), and requires the use of `\SpecialCoor`.

RPN in PostScript works on the principle of maintaining a stack. For coordinates, the top two entries represent the x- and y-coordinates being used. By means of example, consider the RPN calculation

```
2 3 add 4 1 sub mul
```

I'll use the notation `[a b c ...]` to denote the PostScript stack, where `a` is the item at the bottom, with `b` above that, and `c` above that...

Read left to right, the following PostScript actions are taken:

- `2` pushes the number 2 on the stack ~ `[2]`;
- `3` pushes the number 3 on the stack ~ `[2 3]`;
- `add` takes the top two elements from the stack, and adds them together, leaving the result on the stack ~ `[5]`;
- `4` pushes the number 4 on the stack ~ `[5 4]`;
- `1` pushes the number 1 on the stack ~ `[5 4 1]`;
- `sub` takes the top two elements from the stack, and subtracts them from one another, leaving the result on the stack ~ `[5 3]`;
- `mul` takes the top two elements from the stack, and multiplies them together, leaving the result on the stack ~ `[15]`.

Using this, it should be clear that

```
1.5 #1 add 4.1
```

- `1.5` is pushed on the stack ~ `[1.5]`;
- `#1` (the first/optional argument) is pushed on the stack ~ `[1.5 #1]`;
- `add` pops the top two elements, adds them and pushes the result `r` back on the stack ~ `[r]`;
- `4.1` is pushed on the stack ~ `[r 4.1]`.

Now `\rput`, knowing that it has been provided with the `!` (RAW PostScript code) directive, pops the top two elements which provide the x- and y-coordinates of the point. This takes some getting used to, for sure.

A complete list/reference of PostScript commands (including the above), is available as part of the [PostScript LANGUAGE REFERENCE (third edition)](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf). Sections of interest include:

- **3.4 Stacks** (p 45), which includes an example like the above;
- **8.1 Operator Summary** (p 508)

When using nodes, however, it offers a more intuitive way of looking at such arithmetic using `[nodesep=..,offset=..]`.

Answer (score 3):

That should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\xyput}[3]{\rput[B](\calc{#1},\calc{#2}){#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psframe(0,0)(5,5)
  %\rput[B](0,0){0}
  \xyput{0+1}{0+1}{0}
  \xyput{0+4}{0+1}{1}
  \xyput{0+1}{0+4}{2}
  \xyput{0+4}{0+4}{3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

See the picture below 
[image: An example with numbers]

Comment: Sorry, did you try your code? It gives me `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.` around `\calc`, and it shows also `+1`, I don't where it comes from...

Comment: I tried the code. I am using the latest TeXLive 2012. See if your LaTeX distribution is updated.